Trusted hosts for Python extension for Visual Studio Code
I have follow VSCode
Version: 1.88.0 (user setup)
Commit: 5c3e652f63e798a5ac2f31ffd0d863669328dc4c
Date: 2024-04-03T13:26:18.741Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Python extension:
Id: ms-python.python
Version: 2024.4.1

Python envirenment manager extension:
Id: donjayamanne.python-environment-manager
Version: 1.2.4


I open Jupyter notebook
Activate existing .venv (3.12.0) environment
VSCode suggests me to install package ipykernel
I accept
It raises error about SSL
It suggests me to execute follow command manually

python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --force-reinstall

I run it and get error:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/ipykernel/
...
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/ipykernel/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/ipykernel/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipykernel
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))) - skipping

Than I run follow command and it succeed to install package ipykernel:
python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --force-reinstall --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

As this issue, I can not search and install packages from Python VSCode perspective/ When I search it came back with timeout.
Is there some option to inject two follow options for python -m pip calls?

--trusted-host pypi.org
--trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Or may be some list of trusted hosts in plugin's json configuration?
